# Аутентификация в Web Api и Asp.Net MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Проект на ASP.NET MVC 6 и отдельно проект на Web Api. Нужно сделать аутентификацию. Только встает вопрос каким образом? В контроллере в приложении MVC стоит атрибут `[Autorize]`, меня перекидывает на страницу авторизации приложения, на Web Api успешно вызывается контроллер с методом авторизации, и приходит успешное подтверждение и я сохраняю куки в браузере пользователя. Но теперь когда я запрашиваю другую страничку, например, личный кабинет, где у меня должен быть авторизован пользователь, в приложении ASP.NET MVC авторизация уже проходит, а в Web Api опять стоит фильтр `[Autorize]`. Как поступать в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно понимаю, что слой бизнес логики находится на стороне *Web.API (Api)*, а *ASP.NET MVC6 (Client)* - просто клиент? И вся логика атворизации/получения приватных данных должна идти через *API*?

В таком случае можно использовать следующую схему:
1) Запрос на авторизацию передается в *Api*. Ответом *Api* должен стать токен доступа (*access_token*), его время жизни и, возможно, какие-то идентификационные данные пользователя. 
2) После того, как вы получили *access_token* есть несколько вариантов, как его можно использовать. Например, если хотите использовать классический атрибут `[Authroize]` на стороне *Client*, то можно авторизовать пользователя как-нибудь так, используя `OwinContext`:

```
private static void Authenticate(AuthenticationModel model) {
    var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(model.AccessToken);
    cookiesIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, accessToken.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value.ToString()));
    cookiesIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessToken", model.AccessToken));
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { ExpiresUtc = accessToken.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value }, cookiesIdentity);
    var roles = accessToken.Identity.Claims.Where(item => item.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).Select(item => item.Value).ToArray<string>();
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = (IPrincipal)new GenericPrincipal(cookiesIdentity, roles);
}
```

Ну или писать что-то кастомное, по желанию)

3) Ну и если вы сохраните *access_token* на стороне *Client* (например, в куках), сможете обращаться к приватным методам *Api*.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу другой подход.

Можно создать свой атрибут авторизации. Который во многом будет дублировать функционал стандартного атрибута [Authorize]:

- будет брать данные из OwinContext и определять авторизован ли юзер.
- при ошибке редиректить на страницу авторизации

Вот что-то похожее из старого проекта, правда без использования aspnet identity. Данные об авторизации просто хранятся в сессии.

```
public class MyAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {       
        return MySession.Current.Connection.IsConnected;
        // тут вы проанализируете авторизацию используя Identity
    }
}
```